# React render data with array index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have facing an issue in React js, I want to render all data from rest API and show with a numeric index.

Rest API:

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"start_date": "2020-05-08 09:45:00",
"end_date": "2020-05-08 10:00:00",
"full_name": "mirza",
"cust_full_name": "furqan",
},
{
"id": "2",
"start_date": "2020-05-08 02:45:00",
"end_date": "2020-05-08 03:00:00",
"full_name": "mirza",
"cust_full_name": "ahmed",
},
{
"id": "3",
"start_date": "2020-05-08 06:45:00",
"end_date": "2020-05-08 07:00:00",
"full_name": "mirza",
"cust_full_name": "ali",
}
]
```

my code:

```
render() 
{ 

  let FullNameSlot1 = null   //FullNameSlot
  let SecondFullNameSlot1 = null

  let BaberNameSlot1 = null    //BaberNameSlot
  let SecondBaberNameSlot1 = null    


  if (this.state.appointmentdata && this.state.appointmentdata.length
    this.state.appointmentdata[0].start_date.toString() > this.state.newprevious   
    )
    {
    FullNameSlot1 = (
          <p key={0}>{this.state.appointmentdata[0].cust_full_name}</p>
        )

      BaberNameSlot1 = (
        <p key={0}>{this.state.appointmentdata[0].full_name}</p>
      )
 }
```

i want to render data with array {index}

```
if (this.state.appointmentdata && this.state.appointmentdata.length
  this.state.appointmentdata[1].start_date.toString() > this.state.newprevious   
  )

  {
    SecondFullNameSlot1 = (
      <p key={1}>{this.state.appointmentdata[1].cust_full_name}</p>
    )
    SecondBaberNameSlot1 = (
      <p key={1}>{this.state.appointmentdata[1].full_name}</p>
    )
}
```

I want to render all data from rest API and show with a numeric index. Make my code it `simple`.

```
 <p key={index}>{this.state.appointmentdata[index][0].cust_full_name}</p>
 <p key={index}>{this.state.appointmentdata[index][1].cust_full_name}</p>
```

Demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-elion-quqp1

What should i do? Any one help me?

Comment: Could you please make a codesandbox?

Comment: Are you able to map the array to JSX? You get an index for free with array::map.

Comment: ok sure wait a minute [@Leon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10678661/leon-vukovi%c4%87)

Comment: i will share a example code with you [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Comment: i have updated `codesandbox` demo you can check [@leon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10678661/leon-vukovi%c4%87)

Comment: Your codesandbox still doesn't compile, and at this point I don't think your issue is mapping a simple array. Please update your question with ***working*** code and specifically describe your desired/expected output. We're not here to fix the code you provide just to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering and your final condition is a ternary to either map the array of data to JSX or return null. The array::map first argument is the current element being iterated, and the second argument is the current index. When returning JSX like this though you need to return a single node. Here I've used a react `Fragment` and attached the key there. I also destructured the element properties you wanted to display.

[Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
[Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
{
  (this.state.appointmentdata && 
  this.state.appointmentdata.length &&
  this.state.appointmentdata[1].start_date.toString() > this.state.newprevious)
  ? this.state.appointmentdata.map(({ cust_full_name, full_name }, index) => (
    <Fragment key={index}>
      <p>{cust_full_name}</p>
      <p>{full_name}</p>
    </Fragment>
  ) : null
}
```

Comment: thanks, you can check my example code [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Comment: @adnankhan Sorry, the code in your sandbox won't compile. You've mixed up functional and class-based component syntax and defined some lifecycle functions outside the component. But the bulk of your computations are ripe for mapping and making your code more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: i hav updated `sandbox` example code [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese}

Comment: @adnankhan https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hoover-ne669?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

@adnan khan Welcome to Stackoverflow! to render an array of elements you can make use of Array.map function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

In your example it might look like this

```
if(this.state.appointmentdata && this.state.appointmentdata.length){
this.state.appointmentdata.map((data ,index) => <p key={index}>{data.cust_full_name}</p> )

}
```

Comment: have you check my code ? [@sonali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4159318/sonali)

Comment: @adnankhan can you share what is your user story? The code in sandbox can be improved in many ways but we need to understand your user story.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render elements dynamically then conditional rendering is an option
You can use *map()* on appointmentdata and create the same number of elements as objects in the result of API

Sample:

```
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {
            this.state.appointmentdata.length
            ?
               this.state.appointmentdata.map(ele => {
                    return (
                      <React.Fragment>
                        <p key={`cf_${ele.id}`}>{ele.cust_full_name}</p>
                        <p key={`f_${ele.id}`}>{ele.full_name}</p><hr/>
                      </React.Fragment>
                    )
                })
           : "__"
            }
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: please also look my `codesandbox' example code [@Saurabh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3932920/saurabh-lende)

Comment: Hi@adnankhan, I have checked your example but there are some syntactical errors, so I have created a new sandbox example. Please refer: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-bouman-z40ld

Comment: but you miss my condition `start_date >this.state.newprevious` [@Saurabh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3932920/saurabh-lende)

Comment: `start_date >this.state.newcurrent` and `start_date >this.state.newfirst` and so on

Comment: @adnankhan, I have just built a sample example for you to understand the dynamic rendering of elements. If you want to add extra condition you can always do that by adding extra conditions in map function or you can use filter() that will filter out the objects in an array that you want to render. As per your business logic, you can add more additional conditions if you have understood the basic concept of the dynamic rendering of elements.